# cannot connect to Heroku Postgres - error "server closed the connection unexpectedly"

Tags: heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I am trying to use the Heroku CLI to connect a Postgres database in the cloud.

`heroku pg:info` shows the database information, but `heroku pg:psql` fails with the following error:

```
$ heroku pg:psql
--> Connecting to postgresql-<database-id>
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port 5432 must be unblocked for `psql` to work and I was unable to do that. Switching to a different network (e.g. Internet provider at home or mobile Internet) may help.

Comment: what do u mean by switching to a different network?

Comment: @Shomaail I updated my answer. As far as I remember, it was not working for me in the office, but worked fine at home.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the issue for everyone, but if you have a computer set up to [connect with mTLS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-via-mtls#configuring-mutual-tls-and-allowlisting-your-ip) by having a `~/.postgresql/postgresql.crt` and `~/.postgresql/postgresql.key`, `psql` will automatically send the key up to all databases you connect to,  and you will break `heroku pg:psql` connections to other databases

So just

```
mv ~/.postgresql{,.bak}
```

and try again.  If that's your issue, you'll want to put your mTLS certs in a different directory and manually pass them [as arguments or via config vars](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-ssl.html)

> The location of the certificate and key files can be overridden by the
> connection parameters sslcert and sslkey or the environment variables
> PGSSLCERT and PGSSLKEY